# How to filter out not found webpages - iMacros

Tags: url, html, imacros

So, here is my code:

```
VERSION BUILD=7401110 RECORDER=CR

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

TAB T=1 
SET !LOOP 10000
URL GOTO=https://a/a/as/9000{{!LOOP}}.jpg
SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE=Time_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.png
```

It cycles through tons of links and saves each web page to my downloads folder in iMacros. But how do I make it so it only downloads web pages that download successfully? In example, webpages that don't give me a "HTTP 404 Not Found" error.

Also, right now it only saves the picture on the web page, and I need the URL as well. Is there a way that the picture and the URL can be saved together in the same file? Like a screen shot of the PC screen or something? Or maybe even saving the URL as the file name.

Thanks a ton!

-Cashe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imacros can screenshot only browser active area without address bar.

you can get current url using {{!URLCURRENT}}
http://wiki.imacros.net/!URLCURRENT

since there is no IF statement in imacros you'll need to use javascript or similar for that.

Comment: And how would I save it as the current url?

Comment: would I use: SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE={{!URLCURRENT}}.png?

Comment: in general yes, but first you need to remove special characters from url (://) as you can't save files with url-like name straight away.